# Drawing a sub-table in a separate window from object within object

Tags: java, javafx

Let's say I have `List<String> lstcat` which contains the entire list of categories I need in both tables.

I also have `ObservableList<ObjectA> lstObject` which is defined like this:

```
public class ObjectA {
    String MPID;
    String Date;
    ObjectB insideObject;
    }
```

with Object B defined as:

```
public class ObjectB {
    String Symbol;
    int Age;
    }
```

so `lstObject = [ObjectA1, ObjectA2, ...]`

What my goal is is to have a table appear with all of object A's members, and when I click on a row in that table, another table appears with the corresponding Object B's members.

I have the code for the first table:

```
private TableView init(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Group root = new Group();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    TableView<ObjectA> tableView = new Tableview<>;
    List<String> lstCat = ...
    ObservableList<ObjectA> lstObject = ...

    for (int i =0; lstCat.get(i).equals("Symbol") == false;i++) {
        TableColumn<ObjectA,String> col = new TableColumn<>(lstCat.get(i));
        col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(lstCat.get(i)));
        tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        }
    tableView.setItems(lstObject);
    return tableView;
}


public void start(stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    TableView firstTable = init(primaryStage);
    // Here's the code I need help with. Right now I just have a print statement, 
    // I need this to generate a new table with the corresponding objectB.
    firstTable.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            System.out.println("print when click")
            }
            });
    Scene scene = new Scene(test);
    primarystage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
```

The first table appears nicely, no problems at all.

My work so far:

I know to make the columns of the new table it would be:
This would go inside the `handle` method.

```
TableView<ObjectB> innerTable = ....
for (int i = //element in lstCat where objectB members start; i<lstCat.size();i++) {
    TableColumn<ObjectA,String> col = new TableColumn<>(lstCat.get(i));
        col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(lstCat.get(i)));
        innerTable.getColumns().add(col);
        }
```

However, this doesn't work because `lstObject` is of type `ObjectA` but my `innerTable` is of type `ObjectB`. So I am getting errors.

What am I missing here?

(And the reason I am doing this all dynamically is because the tables I am actually working with have much more columns than this, so statically is not really an option.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I believe I may have figured it out.

I can interate over `lstObject` and make a `lstObjectB` and add each `ObjectB` from each `ObjectA` to that `ObservableList` then just make an `innerTable` that way.

Unless there is a better way?

Also how would I use the mouseEvent to have a new window appear with the new `innertable`?

It could also just be a sub-row or something. Not necessarily a new window, just something else that pops up displaying the new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of thought I did figure it out on my own.

It may not be the cleanest/most efficient way, but it is quick and dirty and allows you to keep moving forward.

I made a `return` function for Class A's ObjectB.

```
Public class ObjectA {
    ...
    public ObjectB getObjectB() {
        return ObejctB;
    }
```

And then, just as I said, I iterated over `lstObject` to pull out ObjectB.

So I ended up with something that looked like this:

```
private static ObservableList<ObjectA> getLstObject() {
    return new lstObject....
}
```

Then I made another function:

```
private static ObservableList<ObjectB> getListObjectB() {
        ObservableList<ObjectA> lstObjectA =  getLstObject;
        ObservableList<ObjectB> lstObjectB = new FXCollection.observableArraylist();
        for (int i =0;i<lstObjectA.size();i++) {
            lstObjectB.add(lstObjectA.getObjectB());
        }
        return lstObjectB
    }
```

Now I had two observable lists, so making the Tableview for each was what I had done before, and it was all good.